# Panel appear when onClick PHP JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

here's my problem, I want to make a panel ..that appear on the present page. In there, i ll put the description of a product. There will be a X to close the window and it will come back (with no refresh) at the present page. I tried to search but i don't find a way to do it.

ok then, i tought about an javascript alert() but it won't work. Else, I tought about a window.open() in javascript but i didn't want a new open Browser.I just need an idea or an element to know where i need to search

This panel is preferably done in PHP JAVASCRIPT HTML CSS,
Thanks to help me.

Comment: Listing requirements here will not a solution get you, unfortunately. You must put more effort into your question. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ - it might help you

Answer (score 0):

I think what your talking about is a lightbox

try this

http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/